# Как добавить данные из базы в выпадающий список?

Tags: php, html, symfony2

Возник вопрос. Имеется форма, в ней всего два поля, заголовок и содержание будущей записи.

Захотелось сделать категории к этим записям, хорошо, сущности созданы, в базе таблицы созданы.

Нужно сделать выбор, в какую категорию отнести запись, то есть всё просто по идее - выбрали из выпадающего списка имя категории, создали, получается связь записи, и категории.

Предположим, что в категории существует любой список по названиям. Не важно. Вопрос - как мне в этот выпадающий список закинуть имеющиеся в базе данных элементы категории? Всё, естественно, делается через отдельно созданные типы форм.

```
<option>
<select></select>
</option>
```

Видел примеры только с тегами, как это реализовать не могу сообразить.

Comment: 1) Делаете выборку названий категорий и их id из базы
2) Циклом добавляете полученные данные на страницу
3) Готово!
Только у select синтаксис другой:

    <select name="category">
      <option value="1">Плюшки</option>
      <option value="2">Кренделя</option>
    </select>

Comment: @fremail, этот подход сработает для вывода, но форма так автоматом эти данные не увидит. В симфони очень много кода уделено привязке, и форма существует как отдельный класс (или как производное формбилдера), ее нужно правильно сконфигурировать для этого биндинга, о чем и спрашивает авторю

Comment: разобрался уже, fremail ты ни туда написал, в симхонии там через билдер создаётся форма. А не в шаблоне.

Comment: ОК, но у селекта все равно синтаксис другой ;)